How to combine two XPath expressions with parentheses?
I need to combine two XPath expressions, the 2nd being child of the 1st. Ideally I would do it like this:
(//nav[@class='header__nav'])(/button|/div)

But it doesn't work.
I know I could do 'defactorize' and do
(//nav[@class='header__nav'])/button | (//nav[@class='header__nav'])/div

But I need to keep the 2nd part as is.
Any suggestion ?

You haven't explained very clearly what you want the result of combining the two expressions to be.

@MichaelKay the result should be the same as the 'defactorized' form, but I needed it to be more compact (or 'factorized') like in the first form, because I am building the locators dynamically in code.

Try this
//nav[@class='header__nav']/*[self::button|self::div]

Or this
//nav[@class='header__nav']/*[local-name()[.= 'button' or .= 'div']]

Or using xpath 2.0 you could do (besides Michael Kay's answer) this:
//nav[@class='header__nav']/*[local-name()=('button','div')]

that gives you the opportunity to put those element-names in a variable and reuse them if necessary.

Careful: The second expression uses some ‘ characters where you intended '.  The first expression is cleaner anyway.

I know, stupid iPad. Just updated

thanks @SiebeJongebloed. I am interested in the first answer as it seems elements can be extended with more filters. Will follow up in kjhughes' answer

It's best to avoid testing the result of name() against a string literal as it makes your code dependent on the choice of namespace prefixes in the source document.

@MichaelKay: corrected it

In XPath 2.0+ you can write
//nav[@class='header__nav']/(button|div)

In 1.0 it has to be
//nav[@class='header__nav']/*[self::button|self::div]


This XPath,
//nav[@class='header__nav']/*[self::button|self::div]

selects all button or div element children of all nav elements with a class of header__nav.

Interesting @kjhughes. Didn't know that self keyword ... it refers to current node then ... I think this will help me as I can extend elements' filtering inside the square brackets. I still need to edit my original string but it's minimal
